# Greedy algorithms: "expression result unused"

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to do a greedy algorithm for CS50, but for some reason I keep getting errors saying "expression result unused" when trying to divide the total sum of cents by 25, 10, 5, etc. Would someone be able to pinpoint where I am going wrong? Thank you so much in advance.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
float Change;
int quarters = 25;
int dimes = 10;
int nickels = 5;
int pennies = 1;
int count = 0;

do
{
    Change = get_float("Change: ");
}
while (Change < 0);

int cents = round(Change * 100);

while (cents % 25 >= 25)
 { 
    cents/25;
    count = count + 1;
 }


 while (cents % 10 >= 10)
 {
     cents/10;
     count = count + 1;
 }


while (cents % 5 >= 5)
{
    cents/5;
    count = count + 1;
}


while (cents % 1 >= 1)
{
    cents/1;
    count = count + 1;
}


printf("%d coins", count);

}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to include the *full* and *complete* build output, copy-pasted as text, and also add a comment on the lines in the code where you get the messages.

Comment: And *think* a little... What do you think e.g. `cents/10` would do all by itself? Where is the result stored? Furthermore, what is the result of dividing *anything* by `1`?

Comment: `cents % 25 >= 25` is never true.

Comment: your calculations are all off. You need to *rethink* how it should be done, on paper **first**. Or consider looking for other examples on cs50.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong compare**

The following is never true.  `cents % 25`, the remainder after division, is always less than 25.

```
while (cents % 25 >= 25)
```

**Useless code**

The below divides by 25 then discards the quotient. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57302734/greedy-algorithms-expression-result-unused/57303188#comment101098563_57302734)

```
cents/25;
```

---

Instead in the 25, 10, 5, 1 places

```
// while (cents % 25 >= 25)
while (cents >= 25)

// cents/25;
cents -= 25;
```

---

More efficient code possible.  Hint: `while` loops not needed.

---

Good to convert input to integers.

Deeper:

`int cents = round(Change * 100);` produces a `float` product from `Change * 100`, then converts to `double` in calling `round(double)`.  Lastly it converts the results to `int` as part of the assignment.

Could have used `roundf(float)` and skip the `double` conversion.

For learner code this is a good start.  Note that `Change * 100` can causes a rounding error which would show itself in select cases near a half cent.  Suggest `round(Change * 100.0)`

Perhaps use `long lround(double x)` to expiate the final conversion from `double` to an integer.

Note that excessively large input causes overflow and *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score -1):

Just as the error message is telling you: The value you are calculating `cents/n` isn't going anywhere. I think you are trying to do `cents = cents/n`. 
Also, your`while` loops are checking the value of `cents` but you are incrementing the variable `count`. So you will never exit the loop.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are of course correct. I wasn't trying to do the entire homework assignment, just give enough to get past the most basic errors so that the OP could move forward with debugging the code.

Comment: the problem with these kinds of questions are that they're essentially typos, brainf*ts and as such off-topic on Stack Overflow, unless the typo is of a common variety. This one isn't because the correct approach *cannot* do in-place division *at all*.